# Updating Setting Multiple Ramda lens once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, ramda.js

Noobie to Ramda. So, I was facing some deep state update issues. Somebody recommended Ramda. Now I need some help with it.
Here is my react state

```
steps: {
        currentStep: 1,
        step1:  {
          data: {},
          apiData: null,
          comments:[],
          reviewStatus: '',
          reviewFeedback: ''
        },
        step2:  {
          data: {},
          apiData: null,
          comments:[],
          reviewStatus: '',
          reviewFeedback: ''
        }
    }
```

I made lenses for each step `data` ,`apiData,comments` ,`reviewStatus`, `reviewFeedback`.

```
const step1ApiDataLens = lensPath(['steps', 'step1', 'apiData'])
const step1DataLens = lensPath(['steps', 'step1', 'data'])
const step1Status = lensPath(['steps','step1','reviewStatus'])
const step1Feedback = lensPath(['steps','step1','reviewFeedback'])
```

Sometimes I need to update the `apiData` alone sometimes together like `reviewStatus,reviewFeedback`.Currently I'am handling it through `setState` callback.It works but having 3 to 4 callbacks looks odd. Are there any other ways to set multiple lens at same time?.

```
this.setState((state) => {
                      return set(step1ApiDataLens, response.data, state)
                    }, () => {
                        if (push) {
                            this.setState({
                                currentStatus: view(step1Status, this.state),
                                currentFeedback: view(step1Feedback, this.state)
                            }, () => {
                                this.setState((state)=>{
                                  return set(currentStepLens,currentStep,state)
                                },()=>{
                                  this.setState({
                                    stepReady: true
                                  })
                                })
                            })
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use async-after-set-state-callback for a single update.

```
this.setState(state => {
  const upd1 = set(step1ApiDataLens, response.data, state);
  if (push) {
    const upd2 = {
      ...upd1,
      currentStatus: view(step1Status, upd1),
      currentFeedback: view(step1Feedback, upd1),
      stepReady: true,
    };
    return set(currentStepLens, currentStep, upd2);
  }
  return upd1;
});
```

You probably don't need lenses with ramda, if you don't use `over` on them, unless you want typechecking/selector-abstraction. Ramda.path and Ramda.assocPath can work well enough.

Comment: I had to set my logic in call back. because once the api data is loading i need to execute If check and update current step other wise i face Error cannot find property of undefined. Once API data is loaded to state then i need to make currentStep updated and set step ready to true.

Comment: @shez instead of relying on global push and state, you'd better pass a new state directly, to calculate it.